# Is my CPU fan faulty?

Tags: laptop, fan, cpu-cooler

I bought a lafite iii laptop at PCSpecialist (the lafite iii is actually a Clovo Style Note N131BU) about a year ago, and my CPU fan, which always made some normal fan noise as soon as I started doing demanding tasks, started having a buzzing noise, as if the fan blades were in contact with something, or some screw wasn't tight enough.

I've opened up my case and there wasn't a lot of dust in the fan, nor anything visible that could explain this noise. I cleaned it up with compressed air anyway, but the noise didn't disappear.

My diagnosis would be that the fan is faulty and that I should replace it, however, my question is:

What are the steps and solutions that I could try to make sure that the fan is faulty, and that I need to replace it?

That would include, in my opinion, to make sure that the screws are tight, to blow compressed air into the fan, to check closely if there is not something stuck in the fan that could make this noise.

I posted this question on Hardware earlier, and was told that it was more of a superuser question. In the meantime, the fan started doing worse. Whenever i would move my laptop just a bit, I would hear a much louder rubbing noise, the fan would stop, then start again. I decided to open the laptop again, and this time I unmounted and thoroughly cleaned the radiator and the fan. The fan seemed a bit wobbly when I tried it, as if it would easily rub against its case when it was powered on. However, there wasn't really a lot of dust.

What else can I try before I start looking for a replacement fan?

EDIT: PCSpecialist's support replied that the steps that I've taken to make sure there was nothing more that I could do to make sure that my fan wasn't faulty would have been the ones they would have asked me to do. Therefore, they consider that a fan that cannot be fixed with these steps is faulty, and should be replaced.

Comment: Given that it is only a year old I would recommend dealing with PCSpecialist directly, their standard warranty gives three years cover for labour costs.

Comment: This is what I would've chosen as my first option, however, I'm living right now quite far from the country where I ordered it, and even if that might not be a problem, it is just impossible for me to work without my laptop, and I can't lose a day of work. Getting another computer during the returning time could be a solution, but it isn't really cost-effective, and setting back up all my work environment would probably take as much time as sending and getting back my computer from UK, where PCSpecialist is based. Thanks for the suggestion, though

Comment: I've got an aging PCSpecialist Optimus V. PCS will send out parts within warranty for you to replace yourself. This does not affect your warranty, as they expect their users to perform basic maintenance. Give them a call/contact them online and ask their assistance. Additionally, the PCS forums are a great place to find more specific help on their laptop models.

Comment: That's very useful  information. I figured PCSpecialist's service would be like every other in the world and that would imply sending over your whole laptop. I should've called them before asking here. Thanks for the input

Comment: Thanks @Stese, they are indeed sending me a new fan. They said that the diagnosis is good. I've updated the post so that everyone could know.